# Find double improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How do I evaluate the following case:

$f(x,y) =
    \begin{cases}
      \beta^2e^{-\beta y}, & 0 \leq x \leq y, & \text{where} & \beta > 0\\
      0 & \text{elsewhere}
    \end{cases}$

Find $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(x,y) dxdy$

I am very confused

Comment: I'm thinking restrict the bounds of x from 0 to y, integrate w.r.t. x to get something of the form ye^-by, then integrate that by parts w.r.t. y

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What are you confused about exactly? We cannot help you unless you express your difficulties.

Comment: @amsmath I am confused about setting all bounds correctly. I assume that I need to start with $\int_0^\infty \int_0^y \beta^2e^{-\beta y}dxdy$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

We compute using integration by parts:
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)}f(x,y)\ \mathsf d(x\times y) 
&= \int_0^\infty\int_0^y \beta^2 e^{-\beta y}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^\infty \beta^2 ye^{-\beta y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&=-\beta ye^{-\beta y}|_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty\beta e^{-\beta y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= 0 - e^{-\beta y}|_0^\infty\\
&= 1.
\end{align}